# Habilitar nuevamente un botón usando Update Panel

Tags: .net

Buenos días,

Tengo el siguiente formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el botón "exportar" lo deshabilito en el evento Load del formulario y quiero volver a habilitarlo despues de dar click al botón de "buscar", y como "exportar" debe estar fuera de cualquier update panel, no lo hace y necesito de alguna manera volver a habilitarlo.

Comment: Hola Antonio, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Para poder recibir la ayuda adecuada, debes incluir un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable de lo que estás haciendo para resolver tu problema. Sigue esta guía http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

En este articulo

[[ASP.NET] PopUp Filtro – Usando Ajax Toolkit ModalPopupExtrnder](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2012/04/aspnet-popup-filtro-usando-ajax-toolkit.html)

planteo el mismo tema, basicamente vas a tener que usar javscript para acceder al control que esta por fuera del updatepanel

analiza el titulo `Usando directamente jquery` veras como se define codigo cliente usando jquery para que al retorno del postback que realiza el updatepanel al evento se ejecute ese codigo cliente que en tu caso habilite el boton

En el codigo del evento del lado del servidor podrias definir

```
string script = @" $(""[id*='buttonId']"").prop( "disabled", false );";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "habilitarboton", script, true);
```

entonces cuando vuelva al cliente lo ejecutara habilitando el boton